# nsIAlertService on alert click disable

Tags: javascript, firefox, xul

It is possible to disable the close action when clicking on the alert generated with nsIAlertService?I want the alert to stay until it reaches the timeout and to click on it without closing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, a click always closes the alert (can be seen in the [`onAlertClick` function](http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/95df15895e02/toolkit/components/alerts/resources/content/alert.js#l215)). You have to either accept this behavior or use a different way to display notifications, e.g. using [`<xul:panel>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/panel).

Comment: And if I use <xul:panel>, it will be visible for all tabs? or it is something like PopupNotification, which is visible under only one tab?

Comment: It isn't part of the tabbrowser - displays somewhere on screen, wherever you want to have it.